# How long can a RSocket connection last?

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket, rsocket-java

I understand that RSocket connection is bidirectional.
How long can a client be connected to a server via RSocket before the connection is terminated?

And if the connection actually does terminate, how does it get reconnected if the server wants to send something to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minutes, Days or Weeks?

It's dependent on your use.  Server to Server with lifetime of those servers.  Or Mobile connecting to a backend with sticky routing and resumption.

However while the connection is bi-directional, the client must always initiate the (re-)connection.

https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java/blob/d903e9635a159285b6943ea93156c31aa406ba5d/rsocket-examples/src/main/java/io/rsocket/examples/transport/tcp/resume/ResumeFileTransfer.java